# Opening external app from custom keyboard ios 8

Tags: ios, facebook, ios8, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I wanted to know how I can open an external app from a custom keyboard in iOS 8?
is it by example possible to open Facebook, or post a Facebook message from a custom keyboard, if yes, how can I achieve this?

Thank you,
joe

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to work with the UIApplication sharedApplication openURL: method in order to open the AppStore to link to the app so user's could rate it, Xcode kept telling me that the openURL method would not work in the extension. So I am sure you are able to refer back to the app itself but not open other app's which hopefully they will be able to change fairly soon.

Comment: i show the apps on the store thats open App Store url from keyboard. May there is some solution for that. Please help me if anyone got the solution.